# is there a quick script to rename JPGs in a folder to their HSL values

Tags: ubuntu, unix, imagemagick

Im sure this is possible but:

I'm looking to simply rename swatch type 60px x 60px images based on their extracted HSL values. 
"apple-candy.jpg" becomes 341-64-73.jpg

I only need to run this once. Bonus would be to use a 5px average at the 30px 30px coordinates.
Any help would be awesome

Comment: I can only think of the solution using Python with OpenCV library. But it is required to code, not a quick commandline. I don't know if ImageMagick can achieve this task.

Answer (score 1):

With ImageMagick, the command would be something close too...

```
magick ./path/to/source/*.jpg \
    -set filename:base '%[fx:floor(hue*100)]-%[fx:floor(saturation*100)]-%[fx:floor(lightness*100)]' \
    './path/to/destination/%[filename:base].jpg'
```

Haven't tested the above, but you may need to add `-colorspace HSL` depending how the data values are encoded.